# Objective-C: Could not parse the date from String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

In my `Transaction`, I get the date in format as

```
"2014-11-16T23:18:17.880"
```

I try to parse the date as

```
NSDate *transactionDate = [self getTransactionDateFromString:transactionModel.date];
```

and

```
- (NSDate *)getTransactionDateFromString:(NSString *)dateString {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.Z'"];
    return [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

But this returns `nil`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use a date format that actually matches your date string. Your string does not end with the literal text `.Z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date value contains the millisecond in the end. So use `SSS` instead of using `Z` which will set your date according to the format.

Replace the below line :-

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.Z'"];
```

To Modified line:-

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you `Hussain`

Comment: This is wrong. Why was it accepted? The trailing `'` shouldn't be there. And there is no reason to put any of the punctuation in quotes, just the `T`.

Comment: All the quoting is not needed, only recognized formatting characters (a to z and A to Z) that are literals need to be quoted. See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)